# Unable to run SonarQube analysis of two projects with the same ids?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I have a situation like where i have two projects.
For one project i am successfully able to run analysis. 2nd project is new and it is completely using code and same structure and same modules of project 1 and we can say it is extension of Project 1. While i am running code analysis it is saying modules are already part of project 1

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar
         (default-cli) on project citi-sgp-au:
         Module "com.xxxx.xxxx:xxxxxx" is already part of project "xxxx-xxx-xxx222"
         -> [Help 1]
```

Any guidance on this?

Answer (score 1):

[SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) cannot analyze 2 different projects with the same id (e.g. `groupId` and `artifactId`).

You can change id of one of the two projects or use `sonar.branch` property.

From [SonarQube Wiki](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters):

> **sonar.branch** - Manage SCM branches. Two branches of the same project are
>   considered to be different projects in SonarQube. As a consequence
>   issues found in a project A in a branch B1 are not linked to issues
>   found for this project A in a branch B2. Currently, there is no way to
>   resolve automatically issues of B2 when they are resolved in B1 as
>   again A-B1 & A-B2 are considered as separated project.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the same code and same structure, I assume that the module of both projects end up having the same key. In SonarQube, it is not possible to have a module that belongs to several projects.

So the solution is to make sure that the modules of your 2nd project have unique keys.

Note: if you're using Maven, this is very simple: just make sure that your second project has a different groupId.